# Why static class fields don't collide with other method variables (named with same name)

Tags: java, compilation, static

I have a question related to the following class, and why it doesn't give a compilation error. Usually I would expect that java compiler to complain about variables being defined twice but it doesn't.

```
public class Whiz {
    static int x = 4;
    static String a = "my static string";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 5; x < 10; x++) //no name collision with static int x
            x++;
        //out of for loop
        System.out.println(x--); //prints 4 

        String a = "whoaaaa....no collision"; //no name collision with static String a

        System.out.println(Whiz.a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: read about the scope of variables

Comment: @Jens, I didn't found anywhere an explanation for this. A class field is having highest scope as they can be accessed from any method or block in that class and from out side of the class with qualified name. I would expect a collision between a class field and a method variable with same name.
I checked: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you posted defines variables in different scopes – one defined on the class, one defined as a local variable inside a method. It is not relevant that one of them is `static`. It doesn't (and shouldn't) produce a compilation error.

You can however generate a compilation error if you define two variables in the *same* scope, but this should be an obvious programming mistake:

```
public class Example {
    int x = 0;
    int x = 1; // error: Variable 'x' is already defined in the scope
}
```

For (much) more detail, take a look at the following sections of the Java Language Specification:

- [Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)
- [Shadowing and Obscuring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4)